# SAS SQL SELECT DISTINCT WITH GROUP BY

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sas, distinct

What if a SQL code as below?

```
Proc SQL;
    SELECT DISTINCT ID,SUM(AMOUNT) AS M,SUM(NO) AS CNT
    FROM CUSTOMER_LIST
    GROUP BY ID
    ORDER BY CNT DESC;
QUIT;
```

Use `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`. Any possible error will occur when using this combination Or `DISTINCT` just a redundant word?

Thanks~

Comment: *Any possible error will occur* ... Why ask us this? Do you receive an error?

Comment: yes, what is ID? example, ID can be any id code for a customer, then there is another field called typeofid, in this case I can have ID = 1, typeofid = passport, then id=1, typeofid=driverslicense, I need more details

Comment: being said this, distinct is not a redundant word,

Answer (score 1):

> Use `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`. Any possible error will occur when using this combination? Or `DISTINCT` just a redundant word?

This won't error, but that's just unnecessary redondancy. `GROUP BY ID` guarantees that each `ID` will appear only on one row in the resulset. There is no benefit for adding `DISTINCT` here - and it makes the intent of the query harder to understand.

On the other hand, there are situations where you would use `DISTINCT` without `GROUP BY`: typically when you want to deduplicate a set of columns, but do not need to use aggregate functions (`SUM()`, `COUNT()`...).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID,SUM(AMOUNT) AS M,SUM(NO) AS CNT
FROM CUSTOMER_LIST
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY CNT DESC;
```

We already group by id so no need distinct id